# Is there any GLSL's ftransform() translation in HLSL?

Tags: shader, glsl, hlsl

When using GLSL vertex shaders, a way to let the shader work as a fixed-function pipeline is to call the:

ftransform();

function. Is there a similar function for HLSL's vertex shaders?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found [this tutorial](http://www2.ati.com/misc/samples/dx9/FixedFuncShader.pdf) from ATI's website and this is a [link to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb944006(VS.85).aspx) explaining how to write HLSL Shaders in Direct3D 9. Hope it helps.

EDIT: according to this book, fixed function pipeline is discouraged by Microsoft itself as in HLSL they give you direct access to the underlying hardware.